# Comparison of hitting probability of two Markov chains both with only one absorbing state

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

Let $N_n:=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. Given two finite states Markov chains $\big(X^{(j)}_i\in N_n\}\big)_{i=0}^\infty$ for $j\in\{1,2\}$, both of which have one absorbing state $1$. 
Pr$(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=1|X_i=1)=$Pr$(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=1|X_i=1)=1, \,\forall a\in N_n$.  $$\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a\big)>\text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a\big)>0, \,\forall 1<a<b, a,b\in N_n,$$ 
$$0<\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a\big)\le \text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=b|X_i=a\big), \,\forall a\ge b, a>1, a,b\in N_n.$$ 
Is the following true? 
$$\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}\text{ reaches } b|X^{(1)}_0=a\big)>\text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}\text{ reaches }b|X^{(2)}_0=a\big), \,\forall a<b,$$
and 
$$\text{Pr}(X^{(1)}\text{ reaches }b|X^{(1)}_0=a)\le\text{Pr}(X^{(2)}\text{ reaches }b|X^{(2)}_0=a), \,\forall a
\ge b.$$

[This math.stackexchange.com answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3424918/64809) states that it is not true for an irreducible transition probability matrix compared to a reducible transition probability matrix. But is it true for two chains each of which has only one absorbing state?

Would a coupling argument help to resolve this problem?

---

[Here is the version 2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/345450/32660) of this question under a more stringent condition.

Comment: Try using `\mathrm{Pr}` to get $\mathrm{Pr}$ in math mode, if you insist on a Roman font, instead of switching in and out of math mode which makes the formatting look bad.  You can also use `\text{...}` within math mode to get words: $\mathrm{Pr}(X^{(2)} \text{ reaches } b \dots)$

Comment: Also, long equations look better in display mode: enclose in `$$ eqn $$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=(p_{ij})$ and $Q=(q_{ij})$ be the $n\times n$ transition matrices for the two respective Markov chains, such that 
\begin{gather}p_{11}=q_{11}=1,\\  p_{ij}q_{ij}>0\text{ if }i>1,\\ p_{ij}>q_{ij}\text{ if }1<i<j,\\ 
p_{ij}\le q_{ij}\text{ if }i>1\text{ and }1\le j\le i.
\end{gather}
The conjecture was that then 
\begin{gather}f_{P;ij}>f_{Q;ij}\text{ if }1<i<j,\\ 
f_{P;ij}\le f_{Q;ij}\text{ if }i>1\text{ and }1\le j\le i,
\end{gather}
where $f_{P;ij}$ is the probability that the first chain ever reaches $j$ from $i$, and $f_{Q;ij}$ is defined similarly.

This conjecture is false in general. E.g., suppose that $n=3$, 
$$P=\frac1{16}
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 16 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 12 \\
 4 & 4 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad
Q=\frac1{16}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 16 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 4 & 8 \\
 4 & 4 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right). 
$$
Then
$$f_{P;22}=\frac9{16}\not\le\frac8{16}=f_{Q;22}.$$

Comment: Can you find a counterexample for $p_{ii}=q_{ii}$ and strict inequalities $p_{ij}<q_{ij}, \forall 1<j<i$?

Comment: @Hans : I think this question should be posted separately. If the assumptions are so strengthened, then, somewhat strangely,  the answer appears to turn positive, but I don't have a complete proof of that yet.

Comment: I posed the version 2 of this question here https://mathoverflow.net/q/345450/32660. Please check it out. Thank you.