# Comparison of hitting probability of two Markov chains both with only one absorbing state version 2 under stronger condition

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, inequalities, asymptotics, markov-chains

Let $N_n:=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. Given two finite states Markov chains $\big(X^{(j)}_i\in N_n\}\big)_{i=0}^\infty$ for $j\in\{1,2\}$, both of which have two absorbing states at $1$ and $n$. 
$\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=1|X^{(1)}_i=1\big)=\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=n|X^{(1)}_i=n\big)=\text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=1|X^{(2)}_i=1\big)=\text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=n|X^{(2)}_i=n\big)=1, \,\forall a\in N_n$.  $$\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=b|X^{(1)}_i=a\big)>\text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=b|X^{(2)}_i=a\big)>0, \,\forall 1<a<b, a,b\in N_n.$$
$$0<\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=b|X^{(1)}_i=a\big)< \text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=b|X^{(2)}_i=a\big), \,\forall n>a>b, a>1, a,b\in N_n,$$
$$\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}_{i+1}=a|X^{(1)}_i=a\big)= \text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}_{i+1}=a|X^{(2)}_i=a\big), \,\forall n>a>1, a\in N_n.$$ 
Are the following inequalities true? 
$$\text{Pr}\big(X^{(1)}\text{ reaches } b|X^{(1)}_0=a\big)>\text{Pr}\big(X^{(2)}\text{ reaches }b|X^{(2)}_0=a\big), \,\forall 1<a<b,$$
and 
$$\text{Pr}(X^{(1)}\text{ reaches }b|X^{(1)}_0=a)<\text{Pr}(X^{(2)}\text{ reaches }b|X^{(2)}_0=a), \,\forall n>a>b.$$

[This mathoverflow.net answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345444/32660) demonstrates a counterexample for a weaker condition.

Would a coupling argument help to prove the inequalities if they are true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P=(p_{ij})$ and $Q=(q_{ij})$ be the $n\times n$ transition matrices for the two respective Markov chains, where $n\ge2$. Your conditions imply the following:
\begin{gather}p_{nn}=q_{nn},\\  
p_{nj}<q_{nj}\text{ if }1\le j\le n-1.
\end{gather}
Hence, $1=\sum_{j=1}^n p_{nj}<\sum_{j=1}^n q_{nj}=1$, which is a contradiction (which makes any conclusion whatsoever true).

---

**Added:** In a comment, the OP suggested that the conjecture be modified by now assuming $n$ to be an absorbing state as well, so that the conditions become 
\begin{gather}p_{11}=q_{11}=p_{nn}=q_{nn}=1,\\  
p_{ii}=q_{ii}\text{ if }1\le i\le n, \\
p_{ij}q_{ij}>0\text{ if }1<i<n,\\ p_{ij}>q_{ij}\text{ if }1<i<j\le n,\\ 
p_{ij}<q_{ij}\text{ if }1\le j<i<n.
\end{gather}

The conjecture then becomes that
\begin{gather}f_{P;ij}>f_{Q;ij}\text{ if }1<i<j\le n,\\ 
f_{P;ij}<f_{Q;ij}\text{ if }1\le j<i<n,
\end{gather}
where $f_{P;ij}$ is the probability that the first chain ever reaches $j$ from $i$, and $f_{Q;ij}$ is defined similarly.

This conjecture, too, is false in general. E.g., suppose that $n=5$, 
$$P=\frac1{20}
 \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 20 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 & 12 & 2 \\
 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad
Q=\frac1{20}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 20 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 7 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 12 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 5 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\
\end{array}
\right). 
$$
Then
$$f_{P;32}=\frac13\not<\frac{69}{283}=f_{Q;32}.$$

**Added more:** This is in response to a request by the OP to provide details. Fix any $j\in[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $g$ denote the $j$th column of $P$ and let $R$ denote the matrix obtained from matrix $P$ by replacing the $j$th column in $P$ by the zero column. Then for the column matrix $f:=(f_{P;ij}\colon i\in[n])^T$ we have 
$$f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (R^n g);
$$
cf. e.g. the 5th display on page 85 and formula (2.6.3') on page 90 in [Resnick](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjezNzWsdnlAhVERKwKHeK7CgsQFjADegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fcfm.buap.mx%2Fjzacarias%2Fcursos%2Fprocesos%2Flibros%2Fbook3pe.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2S9tF8Bs3QpzA0FLECZZkJ). If all entries of the column matrix $g$ are nonzero, then the norm $\|R\|_{\infty,\infty}$ of the matrix $R$ considered as a linear operator from $\ell_n^\infty$ to $\ell_n^\infty$ will be $<1$, whence we will have $f=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty R^n)g=(I-R)^{-1}g$. However, in our case, because we have two absorbing states, every column of $P$ must have a zero entry. This difficulty is easy to circumvent, as follows. By the monotone convergence theorem, for $t\in(0,1)$ 
$$(I-tR)^{-1}g=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (tR)^n g\;\Big\uparrow\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty (R^n g)=f
$$
as $t\uparrow1$. So, 
$$f=\lim_{t\uparrow1}(I-tR)^{-1}g. 
$$
Since $(I-tR)^{-1}g$ is rational in $t$, the latter limit is easy to compute.

In particular, for $n=5$ we get
$$f_{P;32}=\frac {p_{34}p_{42}+p_{32}(1-p_{44})} 
{(1-p_{33}) (1-p_{44})-p_{34} p_{43}}, 
$$
with the corresponding expression for $f_{Q;32}$. We see that $f_{P;32}$ is increasing in $p_{34}$. Also, one of the OP's conditions is $p_{34}>q_{34}$. So, to get $f_{P;32}>f_{Q;32}$, we should try to make $p_{34}$ large and $q_{34}$ small. At the same time, we may choose $p_{42}$, $p_{32}$, and $p_{43}$ close enough to $q_{42}$, $q_{32}$, and $q_{43}$ (respectively), also keeping in mind the conditions $p_{33}=q_{33}$ and $p_{44}=q_{44}$. This should (and does) result in $f_{P;32}>f_{Q;32}$, which disproves the conjecture.

**Added yet more:** The matter becomes much more transparent if we ignore, at least for a moment, the strictness of the inequality restrictions on the $p_{ij}$'s and $q_{ij}$'s. Then we may assume that $p_{34}=q_{31}=p_{42}=q_{42}=1$. Then clearly $f_{P;32}=1\not\le0=f_{Q;32}$. If you still insist on the strictness of the inequality restrictions, then you can have it by the continuity of $f_{P;32}$ on the appropriate domain.

Comment: $p_{nn}=q_{nn}$ but they does not have to be $1$. Anyway, your objection is valid. How about making $p_{nn}=q_{nn}=1$ and $p_{nj}=q_{nj}=0, \,\forall 1\le j\le n-1$, so we have two absorbing states at both ends?

Comment: @Hans : The modified conjecture is false, too.

Comment: I see. Do you see any way to salvage the conjecture? Could you please reveal the details of the process by which you find these counterexamples?

Comment: @Hans : At this point I see no way to salvage the conjecture. However, I have provided the details you requested, which may help one find a good sufficient condition for your desired conclusion.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much, Iosif. Allow me to look through your answer. You understand my motivation for the conjecture that strong enough directional transitional flow should increase the hitting probability, right?

Comment: @Hans : I understand that the idea was that the greater drift will result in greater hitting probabilities, but this turns out to be not so.

Comment: @Hans : I have added yet more to the answer, showing clearly why the greater drift does not have to result in greater hitting probabilities.

Comment: @Hans : I have looked at that problem, but have no good ideas about it at this point. Generally, I am not really active on Math SE. Mainly, my answers appeared there because they were moved from MO.

Comment: Would you be interested in giving more thoughts to the problem if I cross-post that problem to MO?

Comment: As I said, I am not really active on Math SE. On MO, I will try to give an answer if I think I have a good idea and time. However, in this case I have no good ideas about that problem.

Comment: I see. I have a technical question. You say every column of $P$ having a zero entry would pose a problem for the direct application of the Neumann expansion. I would think it was because $R$ always has an entry of $1$ which makes $\|R\|_\infty=1$ that does not allow ready convergence of the power series, rather than having a zero entry which can only accelerate convergence. What am I missing?

Comment: @Hans : "a zero entry which can only accelerate convergence". A zero entry where? A zero entry in $R$ will indeed accelerate convergence. But if the $j$th column in $P$ has a zero entry, then the corresponding **"remainder"** matrix $R$ will be "too big", in the sense that $\|R\|_{\infty,\infty}=1$.

Comment: I am confused. $R$ is $P$ with one of its columns turned to a zero column. As all numbers following are nonnegative $0\le R_{i,j}x_j\le P_{i,j}x_j$, $\|R\|\le \|P\|$ for any operator norm. Also, by the Collatz-Wielandtz formula, the spectral radius of $R$ is no larger than that of $P$ which is equal to $1$. So if there is anything making the spectral radius of $R$ equal to $1$, it can only be caused by $P$ itself not by nullifying any column of it.

Comment: @Hans : Have you followed the argument in my latest comment? Do you find anything wrong there? It may help clear the confusion if you consider the extreme cases: **Case 1: the $j$th column of $P$ is all $1$'s.** Then the **remainder** matrix $R$ is zero -- the "best" case for $R$, with $\|R\|_{\infty,\infty}=0$. **Case 2: the $j$th column of $P$ contains a $0$.** This is the "worst" case for $R$, with $\|R\|_{\infty,\infty}=1$.

Comment: Right. I agree. Actually, my last comment does not contradict your statement. Would you care to examine version 3 of this problem with a weaker claim https://mathoverflow.net/q/345816/32660? Thank you, Iosif.