# Poisson counting process subinterval distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Suppose $N(\omega,t)$ is a [homogeneous Poisson counting process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process) with a constant parameter $\lambda,\,\forall\omega \in\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space. Given positive real numbers $T$ and $\tau$, and non-negative integer $n$, what is the probability that $N(\omega,t)$ counts exactly $n$ points within at least one subinterval $[t,t+\tau]$ of $[0,T]$, or Prob$\big(\bigcup_t\big\{\omega\,\big|\, [t,t+\tau]\subseteq [0,T] \wedge N(\omega,t+\tau)-N(\omega,t)=n\big\}\big)$?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is unlikely that this probability can be expressed in closed form. However, we can express your union of uncountably many events under the probability sign as the countable union 
$$A:=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k,$$
where 
$$A_k:=\{S_{k+n-1}-S_k\le\tau<S_{k+n}-S_{k-1},\ S_{k-1}\le T-\tau\}$$
and $S_1,S_2,\dots$ are the times of successive jumps of the Poisson process, with $S_0:=0$. In principle, the probability $P(A)$ of the union $A$ of the $A_k$'s can be expressed by the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), which reduces the calculation of the probability of $A$ to the calculation of the probabilities of the finite intersections of the $A_k$'s. In turn, the latter probabilities can be expressed as iterated integrals, taking into account that the increments $X_j:=S_j-S_{j-1}$ for natural $j$ are iid exponential random variables with rate $\lambda$.

Comment: Can you hint on how to compute Prob$(\bigcap_{i=1}^j A_{k_i})$ for an arbitrary natural number $j$ particularly when the time intervals corresponding to $A_{k_i}$'s are overlapping? Is there a recursive relation?

Comment: @Hans : Since (i) the joint pdf pf the $X_j$'s is known (and actually is given by a rather simple expression), (ii) the $S_j$'s are the cumulative sums of the $X_j$'s, and (iii) the events $A_k$ are expressed in terms of the $S_j$'s, the probabilities of the finite intersections of the $A_k$'s will be expressed as certain iterated integrals, as I wrote. The corresponding integrands will of course be rather complicated, and I don't know of a recursive relations. Unfortunately, this seems to be all that can be done here.

Answer (score -1):

Too long for a comment and maybe a partial answer. First I'm not sure what you really mean, so my comment may be completely wrong. May be you are considering an $M/D/n-1/0$ queuing system with an arrival process, which is $PP(\lambda)$, $n-1$ counters and deterministic service time (of length $\tau$). There is no waiting room. Customers are lost if all counters are busy. Then an interesting characteristic is the mean fraction of customers which are rejected.

Of course also the probability that an arriving customer in $[0,T]$ is rejected may be of interest. This probability corresponds to the probability that there is an interval $[t,t+\tau]$ with not less than $n$ arriving customers. If you know these probabilities it's easy to compute the probability you want. The actual computations are tedious. Maybe you find a solution in the queuing theory literature (google for $M/D$-queue). Unfortunately I have no access to the relevant literature.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvoting means. Is my model wrong? Intentionally I've not used the terminology of pure mathematics but of Operations Research. In OR, in particular in queueing theory, such sort of  problems are investigated.

Comment: Your first paragraph is not while your second paragraph is indeed what the question asks. Is "customer rejection in quenueing theory" the right key phrase to Google?

Comment: By the way, it was **not** I who downvoted your answer.

Comment: @Hans Maybe you can ask your question (without the $Prob$ part, this looks strange) at https://or.stackexchange.com/ Unfortunately this seems to be not very active. And yes, "customer rejection in quenueing theory" seems to be a good question. At least you should find some similar problems. N.B.: The corresponding problem for $M/M$-queues is simple.

Comment: Why is Prob strange? I am specifically asking about the probability and I thought my notation was pretty clear. It is the probability of the union over $t$ of all the sample paths $N(t)$ that satisfies the condition that it counts exactly $n$ within the subinterval of length $\tau$ starting at $t$. I had a cursory search but have not found anything in that vein.

Comment: Hello @Hans, it would be much clearer if in addition you let $N(t)$ depend on some $\omega$, but I think this does not suffice. The left side of $\{N(t)|\ldots\}$ are elements of $\mathbb{N}_0$, so what is the union? Iosif Pinelis has shown a way to formalize your question. To solve your problem I would condition on $N(T) = k$, then you can assume that the times $S_1,\ldots,S_k$ are the ordered independent  random variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$, where each $Y_i \sim U(0,T)$ (uniform distribution on $[0,T]$).

Comment: Yes, I was sloppy. I have edited my notation in the question. I see the approach of Iosif Pinelis. Can you elaborate your approach in detail in your answer? Is it different from Iosif's?

Comment: I looked into this queueing literature. It seems to be very much focused on stationary distributions, so the limit $T\rightarrow\infty$ in which the probability in the OP is 1.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker You are right. Much of the literature deals with average behaviour. The advantage to have a look into the queuing theory is that these formulate models which make questions as that from Hans tractable. The answer of Iosif Pinelis too can be formulated in this framework. I think that you do not find an explicite answer for Hans problem.